# Using stdev command in Tcl math package

Tags: tcl

How do I use the `stdev` command in the ::math::statistics package? I have tried the following but none work

```
package require math
package require math::statistics
%eval ::math::statistics::stdev $my
invalid command name "::math::statistics::stdev"
% eval ::math::stdev $my
invalid command name "::math::stdev"
% eval ::statistics::stdev $my
invalid command name "::statistics::stdev"
```

Where `$my` is a list of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to use that code is:

```
package require math::statistics

set values {1 2 3 4 5}
set SD [::math::statistics::stdev $values]
```

I don't know why you were getting `invalid command name "::math::statistics::stdev"` as an error; I can only guess that you're getting a very old version of the package (it works with version `0.8.0`).

Comment: Now, `wrong # args: should be "math::statistics::stdev values"` would have been an _expected_ error message…

Comment: I have the same version, 0.8.0, and it works the way you have shown. `% math::statistics::stdev $values` also works, but `% eval math::statistics::stdev $values` fails with your expected error mesasge. Maybe `eval` was the problem. Anyways, I found math::stats command which gives mean, standard deviation and variance in one go. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is:

```
set standard_deviation [math::statistics::stdev $my]
```